# Unity: Scale a GameObject in world space

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, scale

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

This is a non-axis-aligned cube being scaled in world space in blender alongside the Z axis (Y in Unity). I want to achieve the same in Unity. I tried to find formulas for this but had no luck, I know that I can parent my object to another GameObject and scale the parent, but once I unparent my original GameObject the scale resets back and I need to scale the original GameObject. Any advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can either unparent it, scale it and then reparent it back, or you can create game object that will hold both these objects separately so they all have their own scale.

```
void Rescale(Transform obj, Vector3 newScale)
{
    if(obj.root != obj)
    {
        Transform parent = obj.parent;
        obj.SetParent(null);
        obj.localScale = newScale;
        obj.SetParent(parent, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The operation I am trying to achieve cannot be done with either of the methods you described. You only described scaling in LOCAL space, I need scaling in WOLD space. Your actions will never skew the cube, it will always remain a figure with 90 degrees corners.

Comment: Sorry, I got your post wrong. The only way of skewing an object in Unity that I know of is placing it inside empty gameobject, scaling the parent and then rotating the child object.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform a scale (Vector3) from world space to local space by using this function:

```
transform.parent.InverseTransformVector(worldScale)
```

To apply to your cube the correct scale you might do something like this:

```
cube.transform.localScale = cube.transform.parent.InverseTransformVector(worldScale);
```

Comment: This won't work, no combination of local scale x,y,z numbers will give the result I am referring to. My humble research led me to believe what I am trying to do is unachievable, because Unity internally uses scale, rotations and positions instead of the matrices.

Comment: as far as I know, unity does use matrices. The Quaternion class is here to help you achieve matrices operations.

Anyway to use the function I suggested above for your problem, maybe you need to use an external object which has the correct rotation and then call InverTransformVector on this object to get the scale you need, then apply it to your gameObject.

However I think using Quaternion would be a better option.

Comment: Not sure you understood my question, I am trying to set a deformation matrix (skew matrix). From what I've learned this is not possible, because Unity internally does not allow for this.

Comment: Sorry, I also got your post wrong. I think indeed what you are trying to do is impossible. Yet using a parent/child solution might be the right way to go if you only want to achieve visual results.